# Debug Qt slots not called

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I wasted hours trying to identify this bug, but I still don't know why it happens... so I resort to you!

I have an object moved to a thread that does some work, when finished emits a signal to be caught by the `QMainWindow`. As simple as this is, the slot in my window doesn't run. However, if I connect the very same signal to `qApp`, works:

```
connect(objInThread_, SIGNAL(mySignal()), this, SLOT(about()));   // Nothing happens

connect(objInThread_, SIGNAL(mySignal()), qApp, SLOT(aboutQt())); // Joy!
```

Note that I actually *copied and pasted* the code for this threaded object from another `QThread`-based object, since I have many of them, and every single slot gets called... except **this** one.

What can I do to debug this?

Here's the declaration of significant slots:

```
class mainwin : public QMainWindow
{
     Q_OBJECT

 public:

     mainwin(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags flags = 0);

     void setupThread()
     {
        // Thread
        objThread_ = new QThread(this);
        objThread_->start();

        // Object in thread
        objInThread_ = new myObject();
        objInThread_->moveToThread(objThread_);

        // Connect
        connect(objInThread_, SIGNAL(mySignal()), this, SLOT(about()));
    }

 // ...

 public slots:

     void loadSettings();

     void about();

 // ...
 }
```

And the `about` slot is simply as follows:

```
void mainwin::about()
{
     qWarning("ABOUT");
}
```

The threaded object function is the following:

```
void myObject::fire()
{
    qWarning("this is threaded");

    emit mySignal();
}
```

Comment: Does your MainWindow class has `Q_OBJECT` declared? Is corresponding moc file generated?

Comment: Yes, it has. Both threaded objects and main window have `Q_OBJECT` declared. And yes, both threaded and main window classes get their respective MOC files...

Comment: Did you check what `connect(objInThread_, SIGNAL(mySignal()), this, SLOT(about()));` returns?

Comment: Ok, I simply dumped the return values: `bool p = connect(..., this, SLOT(about()));` and `bool q = connect(..., qApp, SLOT(aboutQt()));`, and the results of `qWarning(">>>> this %d qApp %d", p, q);` is the (expected?) `>>>> this 1 qApp 1`.

Comment: And you are sure your `about()` slot is never executed? You could try running qmake, and cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Comment: Could you post more of your code please? Specifically the slot declaration?

Comment: Are you using multiple inheritance for the class associated with the `this` object (anywhere in the tree - above or below)?  If so, does the class of the object referenced by `this` at runtime exactly match the class that calls `connect()`?  If not - this is a problem I have run into with Qt.  In such a case, the actual *numeric value* of the `this` pointer does not match (even though the compiler is designed to have it pass an equality check).

Comment: I've added the code to my question, so no, I'm using a very basic inheritance from `QMainWindow`. Moreover, *all* other thread-based objects do work, this is just another one. By the way, I've also tried to remove and recompile. No change whatsoever...

Comment: You need to paste a self-contained, minimal example. You can go about it as follows: 1. Concatenate all .h and .cpp files in one file called "main.cpp", add #include "main.moc" at the end, set up a new project, add that one source to it, run qmake, build. 2. Add it to source control. 3. Start throwing things out that don't make a difference, re-run. If you get lost, revert to a previous version. 4. Eventually you either hit your bug or have something that can be posted here.

Comment: Can you please also post the full function (including declaration) of the code that calls `connect()`?  Thanks.

Comment: I've added the function that calls `connect`, but I am sorry I am not allowed to show the code, and to produce a minimal example by hand is not easy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that the EventLoop of the thread where the slot functions should be executed is running? In order to process a slot function the corresponding EventLoop has to be running via the exec(...) ( - at least I think it is called exec) function.

Some more clarification: Each Q_OBJECT belongs to a thread. This can be changed by the moveToThread() function. The corresponding thread's event loop has to be running in order to process the slot function.

EDIT: my guess is that your thread (what you created) does not have an eventloop executing.

Comment: Well, my guess is that it is running. The `QMainWindow` is in the main thread, the threaded function gets run since I see the output of `qWarning` inside it. After that it emits a signal but the slot it is connected to isn't executed *inside the* `QMainWindow`; if I connect to a `qApp` slot it works...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the header file for mainwin is added to the HEADERS of your .pro file ?

```
HEADERS += "Header file of mainwin declaration"
```

Comment: Yes, it is. I have included everything, to be clear, the `objInThread_` class has some functions that are, each, executed in a thread. All functions except this one work.